# How to deal with NaN when comparing dates in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas Series of NaN's and dates

eg.

```
# In the codebase this is being generated and used elsewhere, so changing the format would be a pain
x = pd.Series([
   np.nan, 
   np.nan, 
   pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').date(),
   np.nan,
   pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01').date()
])
```

The questions is whether the most recent date (if there is one) is greater than '2021-06-01'

I can't do

```
x.max() > pd.to_datetime('2021-06-01')
```

because `x.max()` returns `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.date'`

This is because pandas does not want to compare the float `np.nan` to a date.

However, if I do `x.fillna(pd.NaT).max()` it is still unhappy and throws warnings that `np.NaT` should not be compared to dates.

What is the appropriate way to do this in Pandas.

Comment: "*pandas does not want to compare the float np.nan to a date*" - I would not want to do so either, because it makes no sense to me. I think the problem originates from the fact that you use date objects - pandas datetime does not handle date and time separately. Why not simply use pandas datetime? Just drop the `.date()` in your creation of `x` and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out NaN's beforehand:

```
x[~x.isnull()].max()
```

It finds the maximum of not nulls, and the output is correct:

```
datetime.date(2020, 2, 1)
```